# Can a meromorphic function be written as ratio of holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Well, I want to know whether a meromorphic function can be written as ratio of two holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ or on a *Riemann surface*.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Locally, yes, by definition. But not globally: every holomorphic function on, say, the Riemann sphere is constant, so you can't ever get any interesting meromorphic functions that way.

Comment: ok I understand, if it is non compact riemann surface then?

Comment: A meromorphic function can indeed be written as a ratio of two functions each holomorphic on $\Bbb C$. Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133306/is-a-meromorphic-function-always-a-ratio-of-two-holomorphic-functions

Comment: I believe that the top answer in anon's link answers Patience's question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

a) On a **compact** Riemann surface $X$  holomorphic functions are constant so that the the quotients of holomorphic functions are just the constants too.  In formulas:  $$\mathcal O(X)=\mathbb C \; ,\quad \text{Frac} (\mathcal O(X))=\mathbb C$$ However a deep theorem (*Riemann's Existence Theorem*) assures us that there exists a non-constant meromorphic function on $X$ and  that these  meromorphic functions form a finitely generated field of transcendence degree one over $\mathbb C$ ($\;trdeg_ \mathbb C\mathcal M(X)=1$), so that the answer to your question is negative for compact Riemann surfaces: $$\text{Frac} (\mathcal O(X))=\mathbb C \subsetneq \mathcal M(X)$$

b) On a **non-compact** Riemann surface $Y$ however another difficult theorem, first  proved only in 1948 by Behnke and Stein, says that indeed every meromorphic function *is* the quotient of two holomorphic functions . In formula: $$ \text{Frac} (\mathcal O(Y))= \mathcal M(Y)          $$
The modern point of view is that this is an easy consequence of the difficult result that $Y$ is a  Stein manifold, the analogue in complex-analytic geometry of an affine algebraic variety.

**Bibliography** As usual, Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces* is the best reference for these questions.