# Equivalent definitions of meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

My complex analysis course gives the following definition of a meromorphic function:

"A function $f\colon A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic if it is holomorphic on $A$ except for isolated singularities, which should be poles. "

Searching through the web, I found that some authors or websites define a meromorphic function as a quotient of two holomorphic functions e.g. the wikipedia page mentions this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function

Could anybody give me a brief outline of the proof why these two definitions are equivalent, or give me an (internet-accessible) reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A proof of this is outlined in, I think, the exercises in Gamelin's book. Not sure if you have access to those though.

Comment: See [Is a meromorphic function always a ratio of two holomorphic functions?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133306/is-a-meromorphic-function-always-a-ratio-of-two-holomorphic-functions).

Comment: $f$ should be defined on $A\setminus E,$ where $E$ is a discrete subset of $A.$

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence of the two "definitions" is a consequence of [Weierstrass Factorisation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), which has a relatively long proof.